# Consulta para obtener tarea que esta en los próximos 15 días a entregar

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hola estoy realizando una consulta para obtener las tareas que están por vencerse dentro de un rango de 15.
Ejemplo si hace un mes se creo una tarea y esa tarea la tengo que entregar dentro de 11 días, esta consulta deberá traerme esa tarea ya que estará dentro del rango de 15 días.
Esto es lo que he echo pero no me esta funcionando.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tareas  WHERE CURDATE() < FechaEntrega + INTERVAL 15 DAY;
```

Dentro de mi base de datos tengo fechadeentrega, fecha finalizada(cuando ya se entrego), fechacreacion, status(esta siempre y cuando no se allá entregado aparecerá en proceso) y bueno otras columnas que son irrelevantes, aquí lo que me interesa es obtener esa tarea dentro de ese rango.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el operador `having` para realizar operaciones, de esta manera solo tendré los registros que cumplan la condición de un rango de 15 días, utilizó `DATEDIFF()` para saber cuantos días de diferencia hay entre hoy y la fechaEntrega y el resultado es menor a 16 quiere decir que se encuentra entre el rango de los 15 días

```
SELECT * FROM tareas HAVING DATEDIFF(DATE(FechaEntrega), CURDATE()) < 16
```

Answer (score 0):

En **MySQL** podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
select * 
from tareas 
where fechaEntrega >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -15 DAY)
```

En tu **clausula where** filtras todas las fechas de entrega >= que 15 días anteriores a la fecha actual, para ello usas la **función DATE_ADD**, restándole 15 días a la fecha actual, para ello le pasas como parámetro a la **función DATE_ADD** un primer parámetro que seria la fecha actual, y como segundo parámetro un valor negativo (-15) de la cantidad de días, de esta forma obtienes una fecha 15 días anterior a la fecha actual con la que hacer la comparación con el **campo fechaEntrega**.

Comment: @LuisCazares podrias decirme si esta consulta cumple con lo que debatimos hace unos dias, gracias

Answer (score 0):

la consulta quedo asi:

```
select * 
from tareas 
where FechaEntrega  BETWEEN curdate() AND DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL +14 DAY);
```